# Initializer list issue in constructor

Tags: c++, c++11, initializer-list, stdinitializerlist

I have a hard time understanding how `std::initializer_list` works. I [checked other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/initializer-list), but found nothing relevant (or maybe I didn't see it?).

Say I have this:

```
template<typename T> 
struct Point
{
    T x,y;
};

template<typename T> 
struct A
{
    std::vector<Point<T>> v;
};
```

Then I can build with:

```
int main()
{
   A<int> a{ std::vector<Point<int>> { {4,4}, {5,5},{6,6} } };
}
```

But I'd like to make thing simpler, so I can write:

```
int main()
{
   A<int> a( { {4,4}, {5,5},{6,6} } );
}
```

I tried:

```
template<typename T> 
struct A
{
    std::vector<Point<T>> v;
    template<typename U>
    A( const std::initializer_list<Point<U>>& il ) : v{il}
    {}
};
```

But this fails, [see live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7e9d880743796012).

How can I write a constructor allowing this? Is this even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your desired syntax almost works (without adding a constructor to `A`), just replace `(...)` with `{...}`.

```
int main()
{
   A<int> a{{ {4,4}, {5,5},{6,6} }};
}
```

Second of all, if you still want to write a constructor for `A` don't use `std::initializer_list` for it! `std::vector` already does it, so you don't have to. Just pass the vector:

```
template<typename T> 
struct A
{
    std::vector<Point<T>> v;
    A(std::vector<Point<T>> v) : v(std::move(v)) {}
};

int main()
{
    A<int> a( { {4,4}, {5,5},{6,6} } );
}
```

Comment: Yep, I did indeed missed the double braces syntax, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

Your constructors should not be template, your class is already. `{..}` has no type and can be deduced to very few types.

Once removed, following works:

```
template<typename T> 
struct A
{
    std::vector<Point<T>> v;

    A( const std::vector<Point<T>>& in ) : v(in) {}

    A( const std::initializer_list<Point<T>>& il ): v{il}
    {}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<Point<int>> v{ {4,4}, {5,5},{6,6} };
    A<int> a1( std::vector<Point<int>> { {4,4}, {5,5},{6,6} } ); // this is fine
    assert( a1.v.size() == 3 );

    A<int> a2{{4,4}, {5,5}, {6,6} };
    assert( a2.v.size() == 3 );

    A<int> a3({{4,4}, {5,5}, {6,6} });
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9305f5e9afdd057b)

Comment: Thanks! Works indeed. The thing is, I did template the constructor to handle the possibility to initialize with a different FP type (at the cost of potential precision loss). Say something like `A<float> a{{4.4,5.5}};`, and proceeding to a copy element by element in the constructor body. But I'm satisfied by a solution with same type!

Answer (score 3):

With C++20 there is a feature called [parenthesized initialization of aggregates](https://wg21.link/P0960R3) which allows your given syntax to be well-formed.

```
template<typename T> 
struct Point
{
    T x, y;
};

template<typename T> 
struct A
{
    std::vector<Point<T>> v;
    
};
int main()
{
//--------------v------------------------v---> parenthesis ok with c++20, replace () with {} for pre-c++20
        A<int> a( { {4, 4}, {5, 5}, {6, 6} } );
        
}
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/P1EPexojj)

This means that if you're working with pre-c++20, you can replace the parenthesis `()` with braces `{}`. [demo c++14](https://godbolt.org/z/rsc7r4sGT)

Comment: Thank! But this seems to require C++20, not C++17: your link fails if switching to `-std=c++17`. I'd rather try to stick to C++14.